# How to upgrade Glide 3.7 to Glide 4.7 without changing old code

Tags: android, android-glide

Currently I am using `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'` and Now I want to upgrade to **Glide 4.x** but I don't want to change already added code because its a large project and it will take lot of time to migrate. Is there a way to upgrade **glide to 4.x** **without changing old code**? Like if there any **compact library** provided to make work old code.

Answer (score 4):

> How to upgrade Glide 3.7 to Glide 4.7 without changing old code

**AFAIK**  this is not possible

Read more about [**Migrating from Glidev3 to Glidev4**](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html)

there is lots of changes in Glide 4.x

Like in Glide 4.x new class is introduced callled [`RequestOptions`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#requestoptions) 
which Includes methods like:

- centerCrop()
- placeholder()
- error()
- priority()
- diskCacheStrategy()

**SAMPLE CODE**

> in glide:3 to use `placeholder()` and `error()`

```
    Glide.with(this).load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imageView);
```

> in glide:4 to use `placeholder()` and `error()` we need to use `RequestOptions`

```
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);
    requestOptions.error(R.drawable.error);

    Glide.with(this)
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
            .load(url).into(imageView);
```

**FYI**

1. Minimum Android SDK: Glide v4 requires a minimum API level of 14.
2. Compile Android SDK: Glide v4 requires you to compile against API 26 or later.